# Iterating over observable.forkJoin to handle crud for multiple databases (API)

Tags: javascript, angular, promise, rxjs, observable

I've requirement to insert user info in my primary database and once it get inserted (successfully) I've to insert similar in multiple
databases (APIs). I'm using `Observable.forkJoin()` for my primary database as there are multiple insertion in multiple tables.

Following is my code:

```
save(){
    Observable.forkJoin([          
            this.userService.saveUser(this.username),          
            this.userService.saveRoles(this.username, this.roles),         
            this.userService.saveGroups(this.username, this.groups)         
    ]).subscribe(data=>{                        
            if(data.length == 3){                           
                this.saveInMultipleDatabases();
            }           
        },
        err => console.error("error while adding user ",err)
    );
}

saveInMultipleDatabases(){
    for(let i=0;i<this.allDatabases;i++){
        Observable.forkJoin([          
            this.userService.saveUser(this.username),          
            this.userService.saveRoles(this.username, this.roles),         
            this.userService.saveGroups(this.username, this.groups)         
        ]).subscribe(data=>{                        
            console.log(data);      
        },
            err => console.error("error while adding user ",err)
        );
    }
}
```

Now I've few questions here

- Is `observable.forkJoin()` better way here to insert data in multiple tables.
- After insertion in primary database is it better approach to use `observation.forkJoin` in its `subscribe()` function and iterate over it to 
  achieve insertion in multiple databases like I'm doing here.
- Is it better approach to iterate over observable or promises to handle request/reponse for all the databases.
- I've to implement similar approach for user update/delete scenarios as well so I would like to whether it is better way to implement this or not.

Any help would be appreciated.

**UPDATE**

Insertion code for my primary database in angular service:

```
saveUser(username){     
    return window.appnamespace.DBAPI.insertUser(username);
}

saveRoles(username, roles){
    let promise;
    roles.forEach(role => {         
        promise = window.appnamespace.DBAPI.insertRoles(role, username);
    });
    return promise;
}

saveGroups(username, groups){
    let promise;
    groups.forEach(grp => {         
        promise = window.appnamespace.DBAPI.insertGroups(grp.value, username);
    });
    return promise;
}
```

Comment: Are you trying keep multiple databases in sync... from a frontend app?!

Comment: put aside whether this is a correct server side update sequence, but there's certainly a better way to make your code simplier but i can't see in your code how the db is iterated

Comment: @maxime1992: no it should be async

Comment: @FanCheung: Actually I haven't written code for this but I'm trying to implement like this for multiple dbs however I've written code for my primary db which I can show you

Comment: @SKy it's not what I meant. Why would you reproduce all the calls to multiple database? Feels really, really weird.

Comment: @maxime1992: Yes I know its weird but thats how the requirement is. Basically its like I'm inserting it over another application (hosted on multiple servers) from my primary application using API's.

Comment: Wow. That's reaaaaaaally unpredictible. Be ready for data diversions. What if one call fail to a database? Are you just making it over and over again? Or maybe are you cancelling all the other calls on every other database where it was applied? That's the main issue IMO. I don't know where this requirement comes from but you should refuse to do that

Comment: And you're looping on `this.allDatabases` but never passing it as an argument. So you're probably calling plenty of times, the same one.

Comment: If one call fail then I'll show user that it gets failed on that db like consider I inserted it on 5 servers and it succeeds on 2 and fails on 3 then I've to display message to user accordingly...and unfortunately I can't refuse this.

Answer (score 1):

I think the important question is what needs to happen simultaneously. From your description it seems like you want to wait until all records were stored in the primary database. Only after that you want to store data in the other databases and you probably don't care in what order.

So using `Observable.forkJoin()` is fine I'd just chain it with `concatMap` or `mergeMap` depending on what you want to do. Then all the inner Observables could be merged I guess.

```
Observable.forkJoin([obs1, obs2, obs3])
  .concatMap(responses => {
    const observables = [];
    for (let i=0; i<this.allDatabases; i++) {
      observables.push(saveUser(...), saveRoles(...), ...);
    }
    return Observable.merge(Observable.from(responses), ...observables);
  })
  .subscribe({
    next: response => console.log(response),
    error: err => console.log(`It's broken`, err),
    complete: () => console.log('All done'),
  });
```

This of course largely depends on what you want to do but I hope you'll get the point.

Comment: Thanks for answer. Yes actually once it get inserted in primary db then I don't care whether its inserted in multiple servers or not. I just want logs on where it succeeds and where failed.

Comment: yeah so that's exactly what I did

Comment: I want a log in an array or obj where it worked and where it failed once all operation completes

Comment: Can you please explain concatMap and mergeMap as I don't have much idea about RxJs. I've only used forkJoin

Comment: Well, then it's more complicated. You'll need to use `catchError` for each `saveUser(...)` so the first error won't dispose the chain and then probably `toArray()` before `subscribe()` to collect all results.

Comment: In this case it doesn't matter whether you use `mergeMap` or `concatMap` because `forkJoin` always makes just one emission. Basically `mergeMap` runs its callback function on every emission from source immediately as they are emitted and merges all emissions from all inner Observables into a single stream. On the other hand `concatMap` calls its callback function only after its inner Observable completes which means there's always only one inner Observable subscribed in `concatMap` while `mergeMap` can have multiple inner Observables subscribed at a time.

Comment: As I want to log response of all servers then would it be fine to use `forkJoin` here? Is there any alternative to achieve this?

Comment: well then you'll have to start the inner merged Observable with `Observable.from(responses)`. I updated the code above